# JavaScript loop through array using setTimeout runs into split undefined

Tags: javascript

so I have a wordpress page that is running a page that lets a user build a small comic strip which generates 3 images representing the comic strip.

The user can customise a characters hair, eyes, t-shirt choose between 5 scenarios and then a further 3 choices for how the scenario ends up...

...the eventual output is 3 images or rather 3 panels of lots of layered png's - the layered images of course being the chosen hair, eyes, t-shirt etc plus backgrounds for any scenarios choosen.

This layered set of images need to become a shareable image, so I decided to use html2canvas to render all of the possible images that could be created from the combination of choices of which there is 1260.

I am trying to generate all of these images upfront as html2canvas is a bit flakey for live use so I am trying to do this programmatically.

The image generation runs through my array of 1260 possible combinations fine until about half way where I suddenly get split undefined error, my code outputs all 1260 indices first so I can check that all values are good and all seems ok but I am truely stumped.

The JS code is as follows

```
// THIS 2D ARRAY IS A REPRESENTATION OF THE POSSIBLE VALUES A USER CAN CHOOSE PER HTML PANEL, AS A USER MAKES A CHOICE THE CURRENT PANEL HIDES AND REVEALS THE NEXT
var allArrays = [['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'], ['1','2'], ['0','1','2','3','4','5'], ['1','2','3','4','5'], ['1','2','3']];

// THIS FUNCTION BELOW USES RECURSION TO RUN THROUGH THE ABOVE ARRAY AND FIND ALL POSSIBLE UNIQUE COMBINATIONS A USER COULD SELECT OF WHICH THERE ARE 1260
function allPossibleCases(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 1) {
        return arr[0];
    } else {
        var result = [];
        var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1));
        for (var i = 0; i < allCasesOfRest.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                result.push(arr[0][j] + " " + allCasesOfRest[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

// BEGIN THE RECURSION AND RETURN 2D ARRAY OF THE RESULTS
var uniqueIds = allPossibleCases(allArrays);

// THE BELOW FLATTENS THE RESULTING 2D ARRAY OUTPUT FROM THE 'allPossibleCases' FUNCTION TO A SINGLE ARRAY WITH ALL 1260
// EACH 1260 INDICES CONTAINS A UNIQUE COMBINATION OF THE NUMBERS BUT AS A STRING WITH SPACES e.g. "0 1 0 1 1", "1 1 0 1 1", "2 1 0 1 1"
var merged = [];
merged     = merged.concat.apply(merged, uniqueIds);

// OUTPUT THE FLATTEND ARRAY WITH ALL 1260 VALUES
console.log(merged);

var id1 = 0;
var id2 = 0;
var id3 = 0;
var id4 = 0;
var id5 = 0;

// INCREMENTATION VALUE FOR myTimer FUNCTION
var i   = 0;

// THE FUNCTION BELOW STEPS THROUGH EACH OF THE ARRAY ITEMS IN THE 'merged' ARRAY ALL 1260 USING i AS THE INCREMENTOR
function myTimer() {

    // FOR EACH INDEX IN THE ARRAY I NEED TO TAKE THE FIVE INDIVIDUAL STRING INTEGERS AND PUSH THEM INTO INDIVIDUAL 
    // TEXT INPUTS ON MY WEBSITES FRONTEND TO PROGRAMMATICALLY SIMULATE A USER HAVING GONE THROUGH AND MANUALLY MADE THESE CHOICES
    // I NEED TO USE JAVASCRIPT SPLIT TO PULL OUT EACH STRING INTEGER SO THAT I CAN USE IT ON MY FRONTEND AND ACHIEVE THIS USER FAKING
    var str = merged[i];
    console.log('Current render increment = '+i);
    console.log('The arrays current increment = '+str);
    var res = str.split(" ");

    // I CAST THE SPLIT STRING INTEGERS TO PROPER INTEGERS
    id1 = parseInt(res[0]);
    id2 = parseInt(res[1]);
    id3 = parseInt(res[2]);
    id4 = parseInt(res[3]);
    id5 = parseInt(res[4]);

    // NOW I PUSH EACH OF THESE VALUES INTO MY FORM TO FAKE A USER HAVING MADE ONE OF A POTENTIAL 1260 SET OF CHOICES
    $('.manualImageGen .hair').val(id1);
    $('.manualImageGen .eyes').val(id2);
    $('.manualImageGen .outfit').val(id3);
    $('.manualImageGen .scenario').val(id4);
    $('.manualImageGen .resolution').val(id5);

    // THIS LINE FORCES ANGULAR TO UPDATE ITS UI
    $('.manualImageGen input').trigger('input');

    // THIS IS USED TO TAG THE IMAGE GENERATED BY HTML2CANVAS WITH A UNIQUE ID RELATING TO ONE OF THE 1260
    var fileid = res[0]+res[1]+res[2]+res[3]+res[4];

    // HTML2CANVAS TAKES A SCREEN SHOT OF THE FINAL IMAGE GENERATED AS A RESULT OF FAKING THE CHOICES THAT WERE GENERATED
    html2canvas($('.finalImages'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var data = canvas.toDataURL();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: { 
                    'action':'nopriv_ra_addrelationstick',
                    'relStick' : data,
                    'fileid' : fileid
                }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                if( msg == "false" )
                {
                    alert('Sorry but you need to log in to save your R Stick');
                }
            });

        }
    });

    if(i <= merged.length-1){
        i++;
        console.log("Items left to render = "+merged.length--);
    }else{
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }

}

// TRIGGER THE SETTIMEOUT LOOP ONCE PER SECOND TO STOP BROWSER FREEZING AND GIVE HTML2CANVAS TIME TO DO ITS THING
var myVar = setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 1000);
```

Comment: Question - are all those PNGs on the same domain? Can you use Canvas.toDataURL() or would there be a cross-domain origin problem? Because I really think this could be done with a tiny script instead of this robust solution.

Comment: Are you really meaning ot try to reduce the length of the array: `merged.length--`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you do have those images on your domain, here's my solution to this:

```
var layer0 = document.getElementById('input_layer0').value;
var layer1 = document.getElementById('input_layer1').value;
var layer2 = document.getElementById('input_layer2').value;
...
var panel = [layers[0][layer0],layers[1][layer1],layers[2][layer2]...];
var c = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
c.canvas.width = 200;
c.canvas.height = 200;
c.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
for(var i=0;i<panel.length;i++)
 c.drawImage(panel[i],0,0);
document.getElementById('result_image').src = c.canvas.toDataURL();
```

Where "layers" is an array of image arrays for different layers.

```
i = new Image();
i.src = 'bg1.jpg';
layers[0].push(i);
i = new Image();
i.src = 'bg2.jpg';
layers[0].push(i);
i = new Image();
i.src = 'body_sitting.png';
layers[1].push(i);
i = new Image();
i.src = 'body_standing.png';
layers[1].push(i);
```

Etc.